# Is there a way to secure an RSS feed behind ASP.Net Forms Authentication and still allow readers?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, rss

Is there a way to create an RSS feed that only customers who have logins to our customer portal would be able to see the content of the feeds?  I know I can secure the RSS feed using standard ASP.Net authentication which would be fine for viewing while on our site... but how would a reader be able to subscribe to the feed then?

I'm pretty sure the answer to this is No... but maybe there's another solution I'm not seeing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can secure it with a other auth cookie, with a long time out like in this article

http://www.andreas-kraus.net/blog/increase-aspnet-authentication-membership-cookie-timeout/

but i prefer another approach. If you have a user, than its always good to give the user an uuid column in the database. Then you could give the user a link to your feed with his uuid and can check if he is allowed too consume it without other authentification.

hope that helps

Comment: If all someone needs to do is try different numbers as an ID in the URL though, wouldn't that make it pretty easy to hack?

Comment: i dont say an id, i say an uuid like "173ccd60-01b3-11e1-be50-0800200c9a66", pretty hard to reproduce, not ?

Comment: Ah sorry missed that.  Not a bad idea... The only problem is we still don't want people sharing links, if they post that link anyone else could pick it up then.

Comment: sure, thats always the problem if you want access control without authentification.

Comment: Thanks, this would be the route I'd go if we end up implementing this at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use forms authentication as an RSS client would not know how to handle that. What you could do though is secure it with basic authentication and let the users that are suppose to be able to access the RSS feed include the username and password in the URL. E.g. like:

http://username:password@www.domain.com/feeds/rss

This should be supported by any RSS client as this is a perfectly valid URI. Preferable use https though as the username and password are sent in the clear.

Note: Recent versions of Internet Explorer do not support this anymore as it was subject to spoofing. For example, spam mail could be sent containing links to:

http://www.trustedbanksite.com@somewhere.ru/

This could easily fool users into thinking that they are actually visiting the website of their bank. I don't know how the support is in other browsers.

Comment: Is it better to have username and password in an non secure http connection or a uuid id that could changed by the user ? Many people send urls like that to their friends and dont know that they give his login data.

Comment: From a security point of view there is really no difference in either adding a username:password to the URL or in adding a UUID to the URL. Both are there to identify the user. I agree that people might more likely forward a URL with a UUID to friends that a URL with their username:passwords as they don't understand that the UUID actually represents their login. You might look at HTTP basic authentication (status 401) but I think support for it is not universal among RSS clients.